# Why is my Rails/Passenger app slower when requests come from curl than from the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm having a strange problem with a Rails app running on Phusion Passenger with Apache. The app has a page that makes an AJAX put request to retrieve some data. I am trying to perform the same request via curl (or wget or headless chrome), but it is taking almost twice as long. 90% of the request time is spent in a Rails class, making database calls and building up an object. That code (and the other 10%) simply takes twice as long depending on how the request comes in.

I performed a stack trace at the point just before the bulk of the work is done and it's identical whether I come in via curl or the browser. So it's taking the same path through the code.

There is not one specific part of the code that slows down - the logs show things happening continuously, just slower in the curl request. It's like Ruby is in some kind of profiling mode. But surely that would show up in the stack trace unless its happening at the OS level.

This is true whether I run curl locally, or on the server itself. I have tried mapping the domain name to 127.0.0.1 on the server and it still happens. So I think that eliminates most network issues.

Testing locally with Puma, this does not happen. So I believe that limits the problem to either Apache, Passenger, or Ruby itself.

Any ideas? Any other things I can try to isolate it?

Thanks

Update: it turns out the problem manifests anytime a browser or browser-like thing accesses that action without a cookie. I can reproduce the wget/headless problem using incognito mode. That indicates it's a cache issue although I'm not purposely caching anything between requests. But the bulk of my problem was related to a bug in Ruby Marshal (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14080). I was able to switch to deep_dup for my purposes so my overall problem is gone. I'd still like to know if anyone has any ideas why slow Ruby code can be drastically slower on a new session than an existing one, even if I account for extra time to set up the session.

Comment: Try mocking a browser by setting the user agent header. I doubt that rails treats user agents differently though as the environment is set per server based on `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` not per request.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that and it didn't change the results. But it does seem like the headers are the only thing that could be different.

Comment: Could it be that the marshal bug was eating tons of memory that was not freed by GC?

Comment: @max could be, but that doesn't explain why headless was so much slower.